# After merging two branches some files changed to the old versions and some are deleted

Tags: git, merge

We have "Develop" branch that contains all data for the "part A" of the App and used as the main branch before adding all new features to the "Master".

We have "Features" branch that contains all data for the "part B" of the App that contains new features for the "part B". Into this branch, all developers merge their feature-specific branches after work is finished and we use it as the main branch for "Develop" update.

Previously, those 2 branches (Develop and Features) were merged without any problems, with some minor conflicts. This time when I'm trying to merge, after resolving all conflicts and **only after committing merge to git** I see that Git decided on his own to get old versions of some files and remove some files.

The most interesting is that git doesn't show during merging all deleted/changed files. I can see them only after all things were committed. Some of the changed files doesn't show even after commit.

Changes that happened in "Develop" during last month related only to the "part A", changes that made in "Features" is relevant only for "part B". In 99% of cases its different files and even folders. How can it happen and in which way I can resolve it?

What could be the reason for that? If previously "Features" was merged to "Develop" few times and vice-versa "Develop" was merged into "Features" may this bi-directional merging caused such problems?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the file which picked up old changes is common to both Develop and Feature Branch. As you mentioned that for 99% of the times the files would be different, this might be that 1% where there is a common file which has been committed with old code on top of new changes committed earlier.